# What should I consider before opening an account at a bank in another state?

Tags: united-states, banking

Can a person use a bank from one state while living in another?  I live in a city that doesn't have many interstate banks.  I like an interstate bank that I used when I lived in Florida.  Can I set up an account with that bank even though I live in a state where it has no branches?  If so, are there any problems I should consider?

Comment: Are you comfortable banking online?  (I'd guess 'obviously' is your answer, but just clarifying.)

Answer (score 3):

I still have a bank account I opened in another state when I lived there.  I have no experience with actually opening a bank account at an out of state bank.

With my out of state bank, the basic tasks are fine.  I can take care of most of my banking related tasks with the out of state bank through their web site and their mobile app.  For example, I can check my balances, write checks, deposit checks, use the credit card and make payments.

The less frequent interactions I have with the bank that require me to physically go to a branch, though, make it impossible to use as my primary bank because I simply can't go to a branch.  I've needed cashier's checks, which are not possible to get.  I've had disputes with customer service that I've had to leave unresolved because there is no reliable escalation path over the phone or in writing.  I've also been unable to get temporary credit raises on my debit card over the phone.